# MySQL v.4.0.27 UPDATE + SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE product 
INNER JOIN erpproduct on erpproduct.ProductId = product.ProductId
SET
product.ProductTypeId = (SELECT productTypeId FROM productType WHERE producttype.producttypeName = 'MyProductTypeName' LIMIT 1 ),
WHERE erpproduct.ErpProductId = 123123123;
```

i got an error : "You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select producttype ..."

MySQL version is 4.0.27,  it seems that MySQL doesn't allow Select to specify a SET value. Without SELECT everything goes just fine. Is this the case or am I doing something wrong in the statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extremly old version of MySQL doesn't support subselects. You need MySQL v4.1 as a minimum.

I quote from the relevant part of the [manual of those old versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html):

> With MySQL versions prior to 4.1, it was necessary to work around or
>   avoid the use of subqueries. In many cases, subqueries can
>   successfully be rewritten using joins and other methods. See Section
>   12.2.8.11, “Rewriting Subqueries as Joins for Earlier MySQL Versions”.

Comment: Thanks. I guess i will have to try other approach.